# Collapse Cell but just one at a time

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Maybe it´s an easy question, but I don't find the solution, I really appreciate your help.

I use this [git hub library](https://github.com/jeantimex/ios-swift-collapsible-table-section) to make the cell of the tableView collapse, but If one cell is open and you open another cell the idea it´s to close which was already open and leave the new one open, i.e, just one open at a time. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: You have to search for AccordionView. Go & Search on cocoacontrole. eg https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=accordion

Comment: OMG! Thank you very much! Just wrong search, always happen.. :D Really grateful @Gagan_iOS

Comment: I just created one like you want. You can check out how I did it: https://github.com/MaeseppTarvo/SwiftyPand